# Proof that $\tan(\sin x) > \sin(\tan x), x \in (0, \pi/2)$

Tags: analysis, derivatives, jensen-inequality

Assuming $x \in (0, \frac{\pi}{4})$ Write down a proof that $F(x) > 0 $ for all $x$'s where $F(x) = \tan(\sin x)-\sin(\tan x)$.

All I came up with was using Jensen inequity for 1st derivative using $F(x) = \log(\cos x)$ and $\alpha_1 =\alpha_2 = \alpha_3 =  \frac{1}{3}$ and gaining $3\log(\cos(2\sin x\cdot \tan x)) \geq 2\log(\cos(\sin x)) + \log(\cos(\tan x))$ but what I need to gain is this inequality:
$3\log(\cos x) \geq \leq 2\log(\cos(\sin x)) + \log(\cos(\tan x))$
Any hint would be helpful:p

Comment: @Yashiru See the answer in:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/700236/how-prove-this-inequality-tan-sinx-sin-tanx