# How many times do you have to use L'Hôpital's rule?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives, examples-counterexamples

I'm looking for cases like $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {1-\cos(x)}{x^2}$$ that will not give you the answer the first time you use L'Hôpital's rule on them. For example in this case it will result in a number $\frac{1}{2}$ the second time you use L'Hôpital's rule. I want examples of limits like  $\lim_{x \to c} \frac {f(x)}{g(x)}$ so that you have to use L'Hôpital's rule $5$ times, $18$  times, or say $n$ times on them to get an answer. Another question is about the case in which you use L'Hôpital's rule as many times as you want but you always end with $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {0}{0}$. Does this case exist?

Comment: The spirit of L'Hospital's Rule is not to apply it repeatedly. Rather it is applied in the hope that perhaps the limit of $f'(x) /g'(x) $ is easier to evaluate that evaluating the original limit. Multiple applications of L'Hospital's Rule are nothing but just using Taylor's theorem instead and it is much easier to apply Taylor directly.

Comment: You **could** apply "L'Hopital" twice to find the limit of $\frac{1- cos(x)}{x^2}$ but you don't **have to**.  Most people would apply "L'Hopital" once to get $\frac{sin(x)}{2x}= \frac{1}{2}\frac{sin(x)}{x}$ and you should have learned that $\frac{sin(x)}{x}$ has limit 1 as x goes to 0.

Comment: Does $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty}x^ne^{-x}$ count as an example?

Comment: How about $\lim_(n \to \infty) \dfrac{\sin(\tan x)}{x^6}$?

Answer (score 50):

Sure. Do you want $18$ times? Then consider the limit$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^{18}}{x^{18}}$$or the non-trivial example$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x^{18})}{1-\cos(x^9)}.$$For the case in which you always get $\frac00$, consider the function$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\mathbb{R}&\longrightarrow&\mathbb{R}\\&x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}e^{-1/x^2}&\text{ if }x\neq0\\0&\text{ if }x=0\end{cases}\end{array}$$and the limit$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{f(x)}$$or the non-trivial example$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{f(x^2)}.$$

Comment: You *could* use L'Hôpital's rule 18 times on $x^{18}/x^{18}$;  but you could also simplify the quotient for $x \neq 0$ and then take the limit.  One could say that quotients of polynomials satisfy the letter but not the spirit of this question. (I still upvoted, though.)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Do you think that$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x^{18})}{1-\cos(x^9)}$$is in the spirit of thisquestion?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I can't speak to Michael's or the OP's tastes, but to me, that's much more interesting because it can't be trivially resolved through algebra.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery I have edited my answer, adding to it the example from my previous comment.

Comment: While it doesn't matter for this answer, doesn't e^(x^-2) normally have 1 at point zero?

Comment: @Joshua No, because then it wouldn't be even continuous at $0$:

Comment: @AaronMontgomery: Why not? As $t \to 0$ you have $\sin(t)/t \to 1$ and $(1-\cos(t))/t^2 \to 1/2$. Using these with the appropriate $t$ yields an 'algebraic' solution to your limit.

Comment: @user21820 I wouldn't call the limit of $sin(t)/t$ a trivial algebraic limit; I'd call it a nontrivial geometric limit.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery: Um, to me $\sin,\cos$ are best defined via Taylor series, and so it is indeed a trivial algebraic limit. Bringing in geometry is always pedagogically problematic (despite its popularity), because one cannot talk about area or arclength rigorously without already having much more than basic analysis... Besides, if you want to get $\sin,\cos$ on the complex plane, Taylor series is the obvious way to go. =)

Comment: @user21820 I'm thinking of this problem in elementary terms, i.e. how it would be approached in early calculus. The $x^n/x^n$ limit would be trivially handled by a student in the second or third week of calculus; the $\sin(x) / x$ limit would not.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery: I certainly understand where you are coming from; after all I was taught that way too. But that's precisely why I do not support teaching the totally non-rigorous proof of that limit by vague geometric intuition. Better to just state it as a fact, and then it can be used in purely algebraic manipulation. =)

Comment: @user21820 Sure, and that's a totally reasonable way to run a calculus class -- but surely if you're forced to bring that limit down from the mountain top on a stone tablet, there must be *something* less trivial about it, right?

Comment: @AaronMontgomery: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68585/discussion-between-user21820-and-aaron-montgomery). =)

Comment: Wow, nice idea.

Answer (score 41):

A couple of rather famous limits that each require 7 applications of L’Hôpital’s rule (unless evaluated by another method) are

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \,\frac{\tan{(\sin x)} \; - \; \sin{(\tan x)}}{x^7} \;\;\; \text{and} \;\;\;  \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \, \frac{\tan{(\sin x)} \; - \; \sin{(\tan x)}}{\arctan{(\arcsin x)} \; - \; \arcsin{(\arctan x)}}  \;\; $$

These two limits are discussed in the chronologically listed references below, with **[11]** being a generalization of the tan/sin and arctan/arcsin version. (Both **[10]** and **[11]** were brought to my attention by user21820.) Another limit that requires 7 applications of L’Hôpital’s rule is the following, which I mentioned (in an incorrect way, however) at the end of **[6]**:

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \,\frac{\tan x \; – \; 24\tan \frac{x}{2} \; - 4\sin x \; + \; 15x}{x^7} $$

**[1]** sci.math, [13 February 2000](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=225974)

**[2]** sci.math, [16 April 2000](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=225975)

**[3]** sci.math, [11 July 2000](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=225976)

**[4]** sci.math, [13 August 2001](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=225978)

**[5]** sci.math, [12 February 2005](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=3666566)

**[6]** sci.math, [27 December 2007](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=6046911)

**[7]** sci.math, [7 October 2008](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=6452579)

**[8]** [A question regarding a claim of V. I. Arnold](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20696/a-question-regarding-a-claim-of-v-i-arnold), mathoverflow, 8 April 2010.

**[9]** [How find this limit $\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\dfrac{\sin{(\tan{x})}-\tan{(\sin{x})}}{x^7}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548832/how-find-this-limit-lim-x-to-0-dfrac-sin-tanx-tan-sinxx), Mathematics Stack Exchange, 2 November 2013.

**[10]** [Limit of $\dfrac{\tan^{-1}(\sin^{-1}(x))-\sin^{-1}(\tan^{-1}(x))}{\tan(\sin(x))-\sin(\tan(x))}$ as $x \rightarrow 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/809632/limit-of-dfrac-tan-1-sin-1x-sin-1-tan-1x-tan-sinx), Mathematics Stack Exchange, 26 May 2014.

**[11]** [$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{f(x)-g(x)}{g^{-1}(x)-f^{-1}(x)} = 1$ for any $f,g \in C^1$ that are tangent to $\text{id}$ at $0$ with some simple condition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/810079/lim-x-to-0-dfracfx-gxg-1x-f-1x-1-for-any-f-g-in-c1), Mathematics Stack Exchange, 26 May 2014.

Comment: Your limit at the end just needs one application of L'Hospital's Rule. The denominator changes to $4\cos x-15$ and numerator changes to $\sec^{2} x-12\sec^{2}(x/2)$. Both of these expressions tend to $-11$ so that the limit is $1$. Am I missing something or have you made a typo?

Comment: @Paramanand Singh: You're correct. Using a computer algebra system, I just now found their power series expansions about $x=0,$ and each begins with $-11x,$ so one application of L'Hopital's rule will do it. However, the power series agree until the $x^7$ term, so *their difference* equals $O(x^7)$ (means: approaches $0$ at least as fast as a constant times $x^7).$ Apparently I saw this agreement in their power series expansion in some book or paper  (might have been Hardy's **A Course of Pure Mathematics**) and I incorrectly interpreted the result when I made my comment at the end of **[6]**.

Comment: Ok so the more interesting / hard limit is $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan x-24\tan(x/2)-4\sin x+15x}{x^{7}}$$

Comment: @Paramanand Singh: The limit loses quite a bit of its appeal to me now, because it's relatively easy (I think) to find something like this by trial and error with power series expansions. That is, arrange for two functions (each made up of several algebraic and/or transcendental terms) to have the first few terms of their expansions agree, then just divide their difference by the lowest power of $x$ where their expansions differ. Much more interesting, I think, is when you have something like what I had before (if it had been valid), where it's not obvious how one might have discovered it.

Comment: Would you like to add [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/809632/21820) and [this related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/810079/21820) to your laundry list? In particular, the latter gives somewhat a generalized form that is not just accidental or ad-hoc. =)

Comment: It looks like I need to replace the Math Forum sci.math URLs with google groups URLs, but I don't have time now. This is to hopefully remind me to do so later.

Answer (score 27):

To me, the simplest (nontrivial) way to do this is to exploit functions' representations as power series. For instance, begin with:

$$e^x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^4}{24} + \dots = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^i}{i!}.$$

To cook up an interesting L'Hospital problem, subtract off the first few terms of this series expansion from $e^x$ and divide by an appropriate term. All the following are classical Calculus I examples which are inspired by the above series expansion:
\begin{align*}\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x - 1}{x} &\qquad \text{(requires 1 use of L'H)} \\
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x - 1- x}{x^2} &\qquad \text{(requires 2 uses of L'H)} \\
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x - 1 - x - \frac{x^2}{2}}{x^3} &\qquad \text{(requires 3 uses of L'H)}
\end{align*}
and so forth. You can pick any function you like in place of $e^x$, of course, so long as it has enough derivatives to play with.

You can also use this approach to cook up slightly more interesting examples. For instance, we could subtract off the appropriate terms from $e^x$ and $\cos(x)$ to get their series expansions to be $Cx^2 + [\text{lower order terms}]$. Specifically,
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x - 1 - x}{\cos(x)- 1 }$$
has a nonzero limit and requires two uses of L'Hospital's rule. If we wanted four, we could have subtracted out the $x^2$ and $x^3$ terms from the $e^x$ expansion and the $x^2$ term from the $\cos(x)$ expansion.

What I like about this approach:

1. The examples are nontrivial, in the sense that no elementary algebraic techniques will save you from having to use L'Hospital's rule.
2. You can immediately tell how many uses of L'Hospital's rule will be required.
3. I think it conveys something important both about Taylor series representations of functions *and* about how L'Hospital's rule works.

Comment: You could argue that this is, to some extent, the *definition* of a Taylor polynomial.

Comment: This is a very useful answer in that it shows why one would have to use the rule multiple times.  Each application gets rid of one power of the variable in both the numerator and denominator.  If you cancel lots of terms, you have high powers of the variable and have to use the rule lots of times.

Comment: This is a wonderful answer. +1 for imparting (potential) insight about Taylor series and about L'Hospital at the same time!

Answer (score 7):

For the "$\frac{\infty}{\infty}$" case, if you only use the L'Hôpital's rule and don't change your fraction between its successive applications, then one of simple nontrivial never-ending examples from many textbooks is
$$\lim_{x\to0+}\frac{\ln x}{\cot x}$$.

Answer (score 3):

You can construct simple (boring) examples quite easily using polynomials.  A very trivial example is $\frac{x^n}{x^n}$.  For the never works case, replace $x^n$ with the interesting function: $e^{\frac{-1}{x^2}}$.